# Loading remote configuration file in Angular applications

Tags: angular, rest, nginx, angular-http, angular-httpclient

**Application :** My angular application is hosted on Nginx server. The application uses two different API servers, both hosted on NodeJS/express.

**Problem :** The hostnames and ports for both the API servers are statically defined in the Angular application in my REST service.

```
export class AppREST {

    primary_api_server_hostname: string = "https://hostname_1:port_1"
    secondary_api_server_hostname: string = "https://hostname_2:port_2"

    //using the above hosts for API
}
```

The application design is in such a way that both the API servers can have distinct hostnames and portnames, which can be different than the hostname of the Nginx server itself.

**Expected :** Once the angular application is built using `ng build --prod` and the produced files are placed in the nginx server's html folder, there should be an option to dynamically configure the hostnames and ports used by the appication.

I want to find the best way to make this dynamically configurable using an external json file.

**I tried** placing a `hosts.json` file directly in the nginx server, which was read before initializing the REST api.

This worked fine but can only be considered as a work-around as development of the application using the angular CLI `ng serve` becomes a mess.

Is there any solution recommended by the Angular team?

Answer (score 1):

So, you wanna create a service which initializes and loads variables from a JSON file when the Angular application bootstraps.

You need to create a service which loads configs and will run when your application bootstraps:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
    private appConfig;

    constructor (private injector: Injector) { }

    loadAppConfig() {
        let http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

        return http.get('/assets/app-config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            this.appConfig = data;
        })
    }

    get config() {
        return this.appConfig;
    }
}
```

Credits: [How To Use Run-Time Environment Variables In Angular](https://www.technouz.com/4746/how-to-use-run-time-environment-variables-in-angular/)